# MYSQL + hot to calculate query execution time

Tags: mysql

I have one `java/hibernate` application which interacts with `MYSQL` database tables.

Periodically (say every 1 hour or 24 hours), I want to measure what is the average query execution time from another `application/script`.

Is there any way to do this?